# espacio en blaco css html

Tags: html, css, css3

El problema que tengo es que me queda ese margen blanco en la parte inferior y no encuentro la manera de sacarlo. lo pueden ver en la imagen, intente varias cosas, cambiando tamaños, agregando y sacando margenes, padding, de todo. aparentemente viene del contenedor "main" intente modificarlo cambiando el height pero tampoco dio resultado. alguna solucion?
[image: borde que no se elimina]

A continuación les dejo el código del HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Leading Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="hero">
        <div class="promo">
            <h1>Valhala is coming</h1>
            <div class="countdown">
                <div class="time">
                    <h2 id="days"></h2>
                    <small>Days</small>
                </div>

                <div class="time">
                    <h2 id="hours"></h2>
                    <small>hours</small>
                </div>

                <div class="time">
                    <h2 id="minutes"></h2>
                    <small>minutes</small>
                </div>

                <div class="time">
                    <h2 id="seconds"></h2>
                    <small>seconds</small>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </main>
    <video muted autoplay loop>
        <source src="media/vikings.mp4"type="video/mp4" id="fondo">
    </video>
    <div class="capa"></div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y aquí les agrego el código del css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Macondo&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,300&display=swap');
body{
    height: 950px;
    font-family:Macondo;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #ffff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.promo{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top:270px;
}
video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit:cover;
}
#hero{
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;

}
.capa{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #4bcadb;
    opacity: 0.5;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
.countdown{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 37%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
}
.time{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center ;
    margin: 15px;
    border: 2px groove black;
    width: 90px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(71, 68, 68, 0.322);  
}
.time small{
    font-weight: 900;
}
.time h2{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
h1{
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```

Quiza se deba al tamaño del video? de igual manera debería cubrir todo, dado las propiedades aplicadas en el css, la verdad es que no se que mas intentar.

Comment: Tu body tiene `height: 950px;` será eso?

Comment: Replicando tu código y probando con algunos videos samples, no encuentro nada que pudiera provocar ese espacio en blanco. ¿No tendrás algo en JavaScript que te está agregando alguna propiedad o elemento? Igual puedes intentar inspeccionar el elemento con F12 > Elements para ir detectando de dónde proviene ese espacio.

Comment: @Yussef no, porque lo modifique también, ahí deje la que me ayudo a solucionarlo igual :)

Comment: @Ominous lo solucione de la manera que coloque ahí, quizá se trataba de alguna medida mal puesta en alguna resolución?

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione agregando una medida para los tamaños de la siguiente manera.
[image: codigo de las medidas]

luego de hacer eso se soluciono, quizá el error se encontraba en alguna altura mal definida.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es quitar el height al body y hacer que el html y el body tengan 100%

```
html,body{ height: 100%; }
```